# How to enable support for jsx in Visual Studio Code's Jest Runner extension

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I am using React and need to test my components. When I try to use the VS Code Jest Runner extension on anything containing jsx, I get this error:

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (7:34)
```

Is there a way to enable support for this?